# How to paste when using tmux on a remote server with putty

Tags: putty, tmux, paste

If I start tmux on a remote server while using putty I can't paste using right click.

Answer (score 5):

Hold down the shift key while you right click in the putty terminal to paste into tmux.

source: [link](http://saviouroftime.blogspot.com/2014/01/i-hit-wall-when-trying-to-use-right.html)